# JWPlayer Javascript Load of file

Tags: javascript, php, events, jwplayer

Can someone tell me why this script doesn't work, it used to work on JW Player 5.x but now when they updated JwPlayer it doesn't work... the error I get is:

"Error loading player:
No playable sources found"

Here is my code:
[PasteBin link](http://pastebin.com/492XBYvN)

I would very much appreciate it if someone helps me, I have worked on it more then a week now and it's not working...

Right now I have the newest version of JWpLayer.

The whole point of this code is that the Javascript loads the link from: playlist_mysql.php

and here is what is shown on:

playlist_mysql.php

http://Example.com/mp3/2%20Unlimited%20-%20Jump%20For%20Joy.mp3|9|196|2 Unlimited|Jump for Joy

where the the player has to load the link

and seek to the 9-th second and it has to refresh after: 196 seconds where it's going to load another link from playlist_mysql.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JW6, you need to have a file loaded when the player first sets up.

Example:

```
file: 'dummy.mp4',
```

That will fix the error you are getting.

Also,

```
container.sendEvent
```

Is for JW4.

If you want to adjust things you need to use our new API to do that - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

Comment: Yes. I ran your code locally. The error you get has to do with my answer. You can't set up a player without a file in JW6. That is why I said you needed to add the dummy file.

Comment: Another thing you need for JW6 is the type variable. Set the type variable in your setup, for example, to mp3, if that is the media type you are using, since these files are being served via php / a database.

Comment: So maybe you should set the dummy file to dummy.mp3 instead.

Comment: but my javascript is loading my file, how can I do that, the file is variable from what it gets from playlist_mysql.php, I don't know if you get what I am trying to tell you, but I don't know how to do it... I am already trying for the past week, I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are actually trying to run this so I can debug it properly on a live link?

Comment: Threshold question: Are all of the items in the playlist going to be MP4 videos, are they all going to be MP3 audios, or might there be a mixture?